# Flyway ERROR: Unable to load on Mac Sierra 10.13

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, flyway

I installed flyway using brew and I'm trying to to run a migrate for a postgres and I'm getting this error:

Flyway 4.2.0 by Boxfuse

ERROR: Unable to load /usr/local/Cellar/flyway/4.2.0/libexec/drivers/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar

I've checked this path and the directories and files exists.

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue ([1545](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1545)) with Flyway 4.x that was resolved with version 5.x

*Solution:* Install version 5.x -- I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/21601) to Homebrew to update the formula

---

Root cause is a `ClassCastException` - related to a Java 9 changes ([issue 3](https://github.com/tobias/clojure-java-9/issues/3)).

Run with `-X` flag to see reveal the real issue:

```
$ flyway info -X
Flyway 4.2.0 by Boxfuse

DEBUG: Java 9.0.1 (Oracle Corporation)
DEBUG: Mac OS X 10.13.1 x86_64

DEBUG: Loading config file: /usr/local/Cellar/flyway/4.2.0/libexec/conf/flyway.conf
DEBUG: Unable to load config file: /Users/sdc/flyway.conf
DEBUG: Loading config file: /Users/sdc/code/flytest/flyway.conf
DEBUG: Using configuration:
DEBUG: flyway.jarDirs -> /usr/local/Cellar/flyway/4.2.0/libexec/jars
DEBUG: flyway.driver -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
DEBUG: flyway.locations -> filesystem:/usr/local/Cellar/flyway/4.2.0/libexec/sql
DEBUG: flyway.url -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eddydb
DEBUG: flyway.user -> root
DEBUG: flyway.password -> *********
DEBUG: Adding location to classpath: /usr/local/Cellar/flyway/4.2.0/libexec/drivers/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar
ERROR: Unexpected error
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to load /usr/local/Cellar/flyway/4.2.0/libexec/drivers/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.ClassUtils.addJarOrDirectoryToClasspath(ClassUtils.java:156)
    at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.loadJdbcDrivers(Main.java:305)
    at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.ClassUtils.addJarOrDirectoryToClasspath(ClassUtils.java:151)
    ... 2 more
```